# Div not appearing when dropdown option clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code for a dropdown with search, with 3 options. I want when an option is clicked, a div that was previously hidden, to show. I would also like for when an option from the drop-down is clicked, for that to be the selection that appears in the textbox and the drop-down to hide. I don't know why my current code isn't working. I have implemented the function showDiv(), but it's not working and I can't figure out why!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fruit Dropdown Menu with Search</title>
    <style>
        /* Basic styling for the dropdown */
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-label {
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: block; /* Display the content by default */
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            min-width: 200px;
            border-radius: 5px; /* Rounded corners for the dropdown content */
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Styling for the search input */
        .search-input-container {
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .search-input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 20px; /* Rounded corners for the search input */
            outline: none;
        }

           /* Style for the div that appears */
           .hidden-div {
            display: none;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    
        <div class="dropdown-label">Fruit</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <div class="search-input-container">
                    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
                </div>
                <div id="dropdown">
                <a href="#" id="a" onclick="showDiv()">Apple</a> 
                <a href="#" id="b">Banana</a>
                <a href="#" id="c">Orange</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hidden-div" id="myDiv">
            <p>You selected: <span id="selectedOption"></span></p>
        </div>
    

    <script>
        // JavaScript to show/hide dropdown content
        const dropdownLabel = document.querySelector('.dropdown-label');
        const dropdownContent = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

        dropdownLabel.addEventListener('click', function () {
            dropdownContent.style.display = (dropdownContent.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
        });

        // JavaScript for filtering items
        const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content a');

        searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
            const searchText = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
            
            links.forEach(function (link) {
                const itemText = link.textContent.toLowerCase();
                if (itemText.includes(searchText)) {
                    link.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    link.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        });

        links.forEach(function (link) {
            link.addEventListener('click', function () {
                selectedFruit.textContent = `Selected Fruit: ${link.textContent}`;
                toggleDropdown();
            });
        });

        function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('a').style.display = "block";
}



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your script that should work for your requirements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Fruit Dropdown Menu with Search</title>
        <style>
            /* Basic styling for the dropdown */
            .dropdown {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }
    
            .dropdown-label {
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 10px;
            }
    
            .dropdown-content {
                display: block; /* Display the content by default */
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                z-index: 1;
                min-width: 200px;
                border-radius: 5px; /* Rounded corners for the dropdown content */
            }
    
            .dropdown-content a {
                display: none;
                padding: 10px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #333;
            }
    
            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }
    
            /* Styling for the search input */
            .search-input-container {
                padding: 10px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
    
            .search-input {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 8px;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 20px; /* Rounded corners for the search input */
                outline: none;
            }
    
               /* Style for the div that appears */
               .hidden-div {
                display: none;
                margin-top: 10px;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #e0e0e0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>   
            <div class="dropdown-label">Fruit</div>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div class="search-input-container">
                        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
                    </div>
                    <div id="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="a" onclick="showDiv()">Apple</a> 
                    <a href="#" id="b">Banana</a>
                    <a href="#" id="c">Orange</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="hidden-div" id="myDiv">
                <p>You selected: <span id="selectedOption"></span></p>
            </div>
        
    
        <script>
            // JavaScript to toggle dropdown content
            const dropdownLabel = document.querySelector('.dropdown-label');
            const dropdownContent = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
            const hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
            const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
            const selectedOption = document.getElementById('selectedOption');
    
            dropdownLabel.addEventListener('click', function () {
                // Toggle dropdown display
                dropdownContent.style.display = (dropdownContent.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
            });
    
            // JavaScript for filtering items
            const links = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content a');
    
            searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
                const searchText = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
                
                links.forEach(function (link) {
                    const itemText = link.textContent.toLowerCase();
                    if (itemText.includes(searchText)) {
                        link.style.display = 'block';
                    } else {
                        link.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                });
            });
    
            links.forEach(function (link) {
                link.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    // Set the text of the search input to the text of the clicked link
                    searchInput.value = link.textContent;
                    // Update the selectedOption text
                    selectedOption.textContent = link.textContent;
                    // Hide the dropdown content
                    dropdownContent.style.display = 'none';
                    // Show the hidden div
                    hiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce the issue you're reporting, and the thing I immediately notice is that there are some missing references in your example.

`selectedFruit.textContent` = `Selected Fruit: ${link.textContent}`;

"selectedFruit" isn't defined anywhere in your example. You may need to store a reference to the element you're trying to mutate.

`toggleDropdown();`

"toggleDropdown" also isn't a defined function in your example, so the code will also throw an error here.